# why we use function returning pointer in c and application of function returning pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers

What is the main reason to use function returning pointer? Basically its return the pointer value but there are we can also return the value through pointer.

So why we need function returning pointer?? Is it reduce the size of  code or any else?
Is there any application where we use function returning pointer?

Comment: Why is the question in code font with a scroll bar?

Comment: `Is there any application where we use function returning pointer?` In short: Yes.

Comment: This is too broad to be answerable, voting to close. Try asking a more specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are asking but yes? you could copy a 2Gb variable or an address to that variable that is orders of magnitude smaller. You tell me which is quicker/more efficient ;)

Here is a tutorial that explains their usage:
[C pointers](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson6.html)
Right off the bat it explains how it is easy to use numbers to lookup a safety deposit box so you can go access it.

without the ability to return pointers there would be no point to even having pointers at all. i.e. when you allocated memory for data, a function returns the pointer to its location.  So without that you would never know were the memory you allocated is.

So I guess the functionality of returning pointers is arguably to allow the presence of pointers themselves?

Comment: Thank u Top .bt my question is that .is there any practical application of function returning pointer

Comment: @VarunChhangani I updated my answer with my opinion on their functionality but I'm not sure how much it will help. As others mentioned, the question is extremely broad

Comment: any practical application of function returning pointer

Comment: and one more thing why we need to use function returning pointer

Comment: You don't need to at all the choice is completely yours. It just depends whether or not you need to preserve your original data or not. If you pass using a pointer you will be modifying the original. If you pass normaly (which copies the data), you can freely modify it without changing the original

Answer (score 0):

One example, you can return a pointer to a value. Anyone who has that pointer can then change the value.